# How do I set WCF endpoint identity configuration programmatically?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

How do I set dns programmatically like doing for other configuration as below?

```
  <endpoint address="https://admin.icafems.com/Services/EasyStartTrackingService.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEasyStartTrackingService"
      contract="ES_Service.IEasyStartTrackingService" name="WSHttpBinding_IEasyStartTrackingService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="admin.icafems.com" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>

    ServiceClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(ServiceURL);            
    ServiceClient.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
    ServiceClient.Endpoint.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_ILearningSuiteService";
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You pass an EndpointIdentity to the constructor of the EndpointAddress

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628618.aspx